# Creating Tabs in Tkinter Python using Notebook causing the frame to shrink

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tabs

I have this simple project right here and i created some tabs on this one but the tabs made the entire main frame to shrink i want to be bigger as i want it. Please help me. I want those tabs to be just like chrome tabs on the corner and the entire main frame.

the current view is something like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydVzg.png) but what i want to is to fit in the original size of the main frame without shrinking it [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deorA.png)

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

mainwindow = Tk()
mainwindow.title('Student Database')
mainwindow.config(bg='#4d4d4d')


#centering the main window on screen
def centrewindow(w, h):
    ws = mainwindow.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = mainwindow.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = (hs/2) -(h/2)
    mainwindow.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
centrewindow(550, 400)

mainframe = Frame(width= 1000, height= 600, bg= '#d9d9d9', bd= 0.3, relief= SOLID)
mainframe.pack(pady=100, padx= 100)

tabcontrol = ttk.Notebook(mainframe)


tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabcontrol)
tabcontrol.add(tab1, text='Tab no. 1')
l1 = Label(tab1, text='Hello Its Tab 1')
l1.pack()

tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabcontrol)
tabcontrol.add(tab2, text='Tab no. 2')
l2 = Label(tab2, text='Hello Its Tab 2')
l2.pack()

tabcontrol.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
mainwindow.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the fill and expand command for every Frame in the chain. You are missing this one:

```
mainframe.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
```

Note that the width and height setting of a Frame is ignored when something is placed in the Frame.

Comment: Thanks a lot but i think the main frame is a little larger now

Comment: @YashuCッ You can add back the paddings from your original code.